# get Access Token from Azure AD Java

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, azure, api

I want to get a Azure RateCard Json response via Billing REST Api. 
For this I use the following code in eclipse:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;

public class RateCardRest {

public static String getAccessToken(String tenantId, String clientId, String clientSecret)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String endpoint = String.format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token", tenantId);
    String postBody = String.format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&resource=%s",
            clientId, clientSecret, "https://management.azure.com/");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(endpoint).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postBody.getBytes());
    conn.connect();
//      If you want to see the response content, please use the commented code below.
//      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
//      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
//      String line = null;
//      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//          builder.append(line);
//      }
//      reader.close();
//      System.out.println(builder.toString());
//      The output for access token is {"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3600","ext_expires_in":"3600","expires_on":"1550660092","not_before":"1550656192","resource":"https://management.azure.com/","access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL...."}
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(conn.getInputStream());
    String accessToken = null;
    while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String name = parser.getCurrentName();
        if ("access_token".equals(name)) {
            parser.nextToken();
            accessToken = parser.getText();
        }
    }
    return accessToken;
}

public static String getRateCard(String subscriptionId, String apiVersion, String offerId, String currency,
        String locale, String region, String accessToken) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String endpoint = String.format(
            "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%s/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=%s&$filter=OfferDurableId eq '%s' and Currency eq '%s' and Locale eq '%s' and RegionInfo eq '%s'",
            subscriptionId, apiVersion, offerId, currency, locale, region).replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(endpoint).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.connect();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String tenantId = "<your tenant id like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String clientId = "<your client id registed in AAD like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String clientSecret = "<your client secret key generated in AAD>";
    String accessToken = getAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    System.out.println(accessToken);
    String subscriptionId = "<your subscription id like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String apiVersion = "2015-06-01-preview";
    String offerId = "<your offer id like XX-AZR-XXXXX";
    String currency = "USD";
    String locale = "en-US";
    String region = "US";
    String rateCardResp = getRateCard(subscriptionId, apiVersion, offerId, currency, locale, region, accessToken);
    System.out.println(rateCardResp);
}

 }
```

This causes the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/"myTenantID"/oauth2/token
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.nttdata.altemista.RateCardRest.getAccessToken(RateCardRest.java:38)
    at com.nttdata.altemista.RateCardRest.main(RateCardRest.java:74)
```

When I search the URL, I get the following message:

> AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET request.

Comment: Have you checked the response body? Usually a detailed error is included.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean with response body?

Comment: The data you get from `conn.getInputStream()`

Comment: 401 means you're not authorized, so the token you get it's not valid. You're doing something wrong with your getAccessToken request. Most of the time is the `resource` field that is wrong somehow, what resource you're trying to access?

Comment: How can I get the data from conn.getInputStream() because i can't output the "String"? Where do I have a resource field? Sorry that I ask so many questions but this code isn't from me

Comment: @juunas means by `resource` which your are getting token for see your code line  which I mark with ??. Usual case is user often does mistake here:     String postBody = String.format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&resource=%???????????????????????",
            clientId, clientSecret, "https://management.azure.com/");

Comment: @Wuld If you want to output the data of `conn.getInputStream()`, you can use the code which I comment.

Comment: @Wuld I have a question about what Azure you used? Global Azure, Germany Azure, even China Azure? They are different for the code to use different Azure endpoints.

Comment: @PeterPan Unfortunately not because then I get the error in line 28 by the BufferedReader

Comment: @PeterPan I assume Germany Azure because we are a german company. Can I look this up somewhere?

Comment: @Wuld Except Global Azure, I don't know anything about Germany Azure. The reason why ask for what Azure you used, just I had answered a question about China Azure long ago.

Comment: @ALFA in what way can I change the resource field?

Comment: @Wuld Follow the section [`Request URI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#request-uri), you can also use `https://management.core.windows.net/` as resource at here.

Comment: @Wuld I suggest that you can use postman to send the same request for getting access token to see the response body about error detail.

Comment: Same error with   `https://management.core.windows.net/`

Comment: @Wuld Using `https://management.core.windows.net/`, it also works for me.  Please use Postman to try to get access token to see the response body. Here is my sample figure https://i.stack.imgur.com/42exG.png.

Comment: @PeterPan now it works. I get an AccessToken. By Get Resource Groups i get the following error: `{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client /*...*/ with object id /*....*/ does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions//*....*/'."
    }
}`   Does that mean, that i have not enough permissions from this subscriptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to UrlEncode your client secret key generated in AAD.

[image]
add

```
clientSecret=java.net.URLEncoder.encode(clientSecret,"UTF-8");
```

below to

```
String clientSecret = "<your client secret key generated in AAD>";
```

Comment: Thank you! Now getAccesToken return an AccessToken. New Error: `Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: /*....*/`  The URL gives the message. Authorization-Header is missing

Comment: Can you create a new question with more details? Please add the error message details.