# How to make http(s) url connection using crt and pkcs8_key - java

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, httpsurlconnection

I would like to connect to Azure AD using client certificate - not id and secret

The certificate is in a folder, not in the key store

We have some limitations, so cant use msal4j.

So looking to create a token like - [get Access Token from Azure AD Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017923/get-access-token-from-azure-ad-java)

but using a certificate

Please can anyone tell - how to create token using http connection api?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) with client certificate.

```
POST http://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token 

scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&client_id=<client_id>
&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
&client_assertion=<An assertion (a JSON web token)>
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

[Client assertions](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Assertions) can be used anywhere a client secret would be used. You can replace `client_secret` with `client_assertion` and `client_assertion_type` parameters. You could refer to the [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66690966/13308381) with java.

Comment: This doesnt address my question. Not sure why you are copy pasting publicly available documentation, and labelling that as an answer? How to create that client_assertion from certificate , with my constaints is the question

Comment: I removed the duplicate code. Create that client_assertion from certificate, see "You could refer to the [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643465/signing-a-jwt-with-a-pfx-file/66690966#66690966) with java."

Comment: The code sample link you are referring is "signing a JWT with a .pfx file" and also not accepted answer.where in your code are you making http url connection, NOT postman. I am expecting - HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://someurl.com").openConnection(); + .....